# Edit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base in Centos 7 -- qcow2 image

Tags: virt-manager, qcow2

My qcow2 image uses local nameserver, `192.168.122.1` which is not working for reasons unknown.

So, I tried to use guestfish and edit the file `/etc/resolv.conf` to add nameservers, `8.8.8.8`. This doesnt work as dhclient overwrites it.

I tried other methods, given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-include-lines-in-resolv-conf-that-wont-get-lost-on-reboot). Inside guestfish cli, when i try to `vi` edit the files, `/etc/network/interfaces` (or) `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`, both the files are missing.

How can i permanently set a working nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` in the seed image?

Centos image version --- `CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud-20140929_01.qcow2`

Comment: It seems as if fixing the problem with the libvirt-managed nameserver is going to be a more effective solution to the actual problem (because this is going to affect pretty much *everything* you boot in your virtual environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent the DHCP client from overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf`, you can set `PEERDNS=no` in the appropriate network configuration file, which in your situation will probably be `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.  It will look something like this:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
USERCTL="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6INIT="no"
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT="1"
```

Just change `PEERDNS="yes"` to `PEERDNS="no"` (using, e.g., `guestfish`, or whatever your favorite mechanism is for modifying vm images).